# Parameterization of Integral

Tags: calculus

So we just went over parameterization for integrals then suddenly the professor dropped a bomb:

Show that for $A_i >0 \forall i \in \{1,....,n\}$

$$\frac{1}{A_1\cdot \cdot \cdot A_n}=\int_0^\infty ds_1...\int_0^\infty ds_n exp(-[s_1A_1+...+s_nA_n)$$

I mean we just learned how to parameterise line or surface integrals, i literally have no idea how to do this.

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Work it out one at a time. What is $\int_0^{\infty} ds_n e^{ (stuff) }$?

Comment: Ehmmm simply $e^{stuf}s+C$?

Comment: A little question on notation: in your writing are the $ds_{i}, \ i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ the integrating $d$ or a constant? It's not common to put the integrating $d$ in front of the expression to be integrated.

Comment: @algevristis i think its the differential....